# Passing an object between pages - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am developing a hybrid app using jQuery Mobile using the following flow:

1) login.html - calls a service to validate credentials and navigates to appscreen.html
2) appscreen.html - this has links to local and external hybrid apps

I am creating a JavaScript object in appscreen.html for all other apps to use however when navigating back to appscreen.html it creates a new object and is not shareable.

The JS for login.html executes this after validating:

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "appscreen.html");
```

If I instantiate the object on the login page, the object gets created and disappears once the appscreen page is loaded.

What jQuery Mobile page event do I need and which page should it be on?

Comment: You can store the object using local storage

Comment: I believe thats what I'm doing however due to scope if the object is created on the login page when i navigate away from the login screen it becomes out of scope and goes away.

Comment: I mean this storage: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I'll have to check on that, some data being stored may be sensitive.  Thank you for your responses.